# Why does my page jump back to the top when I use backspace or back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problems with my site http://www.acmilan-bg.com . It seems like it loads twice and although I have scrolled down, the page go to the top. You can see this if you scroll down imediately after loading the page.

If I go to another page and use "Backspace" or "back button" from the browser I do not go to the last cached position, it goes again to the top.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? It's not happening for me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary **to reproduce it in the question itself**.  Try to recreate the issue on a blank, new page - have a read of [mcve].

Comment: It looks to me like the plugin you use for comments-> Disqus, is lazy loading and making the page grow in height. And also causing the offset of the scrollbar to change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it appears you have this piece of code in your HTML.

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); }
</script>
```

At the top of the page, so it actually scrolls to the top **window.scrollTo(0,1)** when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I removed this script on one of the subpages and currently everything is fine. Let's start removing the script from all pages...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not a browser compatibility issue? In Windows 10 Google Chrome, it loads like normal and if you press back or alt+left arrow(which replaced backspace), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forcing you web page to scroll to top somewhere in code. Its not loading twice though, working fine for me on Mozilla client. I think you are getting this issue while trying to go to the bottom while page is still loading, so when it completes loading, it reads the piece of coded and scroll back to top. That's why you think its loading twice.